# Как устранить прыжок с центрированием текста при прокрутке слайдера bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery, bootstrap4

Есть слайдер построенный на `bootstrap 4` в котором проблема: при прокрутке очередного слайда, плашка с текстом центрируется с визуальным прыжком.
Как сделать так, чтобы плашка была изначально отцентрирована на слайде при любом разрешении.

Вариант с подстройкой `transform: translateY();` не рассматриваю, интересует грамотная адаптивность без подключения лишних библиотек сторонних слайдеров, функционал стандартного бутстраповского устраивает

```css
#carousel {
  position: relative;
}

#carousel .carousel-item {
  min-height: 750px;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel .carousel-item.active {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel .carousel-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#carousel .carousel-text {
  color: #1d3c4c;
}

#carousel .carousel-text .col {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#carousel .carousel-text h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway Bold';
}

#carousel .carousel-text h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<section id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg" alt="slider1">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-text row">
          <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/dead-tree-tall-portrait-view-blue-sky-background-57002950.jpg" alt="slider2">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-text row">
          <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg" alt="slider3">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="carousel-text row">
          <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
            <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#carousel {
  position: relative;
}

#carousel .carousel-item {
  min-height: 750px;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel .carousel-caption {
  bottom: 50%;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

#carousel .carousel-item>img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

#carousel .carousel-text {
  color: #1d3c4c;
}

#carousel .carousel-text .col {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 25px;
}

#carousel .carousel-text h2 {
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: 'Raleway Bold';
}

#carousel .carousel-text h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Raleway';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- The slideshow -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/132037/pexels-photo-132037.jpeg" alt="slider1">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-text row">
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/dead-tree-tall-portrait-view-blue-sky-background-57002950.jpg" alt="slider2">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-text row">
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
      <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/414171/pexels-photo-414171.jpeg" alt="slider3">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="carousel-text row">
            <div class="col col-lg-8 col-12">
              <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam, excepturi.</h3>
              <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Numquam, quo.</h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Left and right controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
  </a>
  <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
  </a>

</section>
```